# How to Click on all "role=button" on a webpage using selenium and python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to create my first project using python and Selenium, and i'm new into it, it's just a simple project that ask user for his/her facebook username and password, then login redirect to the facebook.com/user/following page and unfollow everybody the user is following.

Here's my code bellow

I imported the necessary modules using this codes

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import selenium
import time
```

I closed the Facebook popup Notification to avoid disruption of the code..

```
##SHUTTING POPUP NOTIFICATION
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Defined a Login `func` that takes username and pass word after opening facebook..

```
  def login():
        #Login
        user = input('Whats your username or email    ')
        passw = input('Input your password    ')
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
        username = driver.find_element_by_name("email")
        username.send_keys(user)
        password = driver.find_element_by_name("pass")
        password.send_keys(passw)
        password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Next I just created a 3 sec. Time function

```
  def timeToSleep():
     time.sleep(3)
```

The getPage function is the function for redirecting to my destination i.e User following

```
  def getPage():
        ##Get Page
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/Username/ID/following")
```

This is the click function to click on the places i want and this is where my problem is..
I will like to start clicking on all following with the click funcion bellow..
[Check img]

```
  def click():
        xpath = "//a[@role='button']"
        a=driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)
        for posts in a:
              posts.click()
```

[CLICK ON FOLLOWING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CaxE.png)

But my problem now is this (The following button doesn't have any class or id except for an anchor attribute "role='button')..

The code would have worked fine but they are other elements on the webpage with same role='button' attribute, like the pix below:
[Toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oV96r.png)
The facebook toolbars have same role button stuff..
My question is this :
How do i make Selenium skip the toolbar and start clicking from the Following buttons..

So Sorry if my explanation is bad...
I'll gladly appreciate any help from any body..

Thanks in Advance

Comment: please add html

Comment: Hi @prany.. . What html am I to add?

Comment: Add the HTML code of `Following` buttons. I saw the screenshot you given. Each person displayed in a small card, so please show HTML code of two cards. So that we can know the difference between card and the relationship of the `Following` button with the card.

Comment: Hey @prany..
I checked the id of all the cards.. they ain't the same..

Comment: Hey @prany..
I checked the id of all the cards.. they ain't the same..
`<a role="button" class="_42ft _4jy0 _63_s _5lzl _4jy3 _517h _51sy" ajaxify="/ajax/follow/unfollow_profile.php?profile_id=10001003" data-profileid="10001003" data-followed="1" href="#" rel="async-post" id="u_0_2v"><i class="_3-8_ img sp_z__FZRp4XxF sx_c950c7"></i>Following</a>`

what changes is the id and ajaxify...
i wanted to loop through the id and get what i want but found out that each card doesn't have difference of one, for example
1st card id can be u_ f _30 then second card id will be u _ f _ 3f and all that

Answer (score 0):

I follow Mark Zuckerberg on Facebook and here is the xpath to click on unfollow link :

```
//a[text()='Mark Zuckerberg']/../../following-sibling::div[2]/a
```

Similarly, you can replace the name of Person in your case to click on Unfollow link.

If None of yours friends follow the Person who you follow, then you can use this XPATH also :

```
//a[contains(@data-hovercard,'/ajax/hovercard/user.php?')]/../../following-sibling::div/a
```

Which is independent of the Person Name. Note that this will give you list of web elements not a single element. [This is quite suitable for your requirement as you want to click on every unfollow link].

HTH!

Comment: Thanks @cruisepandey I will check it out and get back to you..                                                               Ziky

Comment: @IsaacFrank : Sure. Let me know if you are facing any problem regarding this.

Comment: Hello @cruisepandey,
All i'm trying to do is to click all unfollow button that shows here (facebook.com/zikyfranky/following) ..

Meaning that it will unfollow everybody and also pages..

Thanks,
As i wait ur usual cooperation

Comment: @IsaacFrank  : I can not do your home work buddy. The provided Xpath are reference for how you can achieve your goal. Good luck with that.